# Ac dc circuits electronics

Tags: power-electronics

We know V(rms) is the equivalent dc voltage for same power decipation. But in half wave rectifier case wikipedia says V(dc) =V(avg) and not V(rms) .
Why it is saying V(dc) =V(avg) and not V(dc) =V(rms)?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier

[image]

Comment: Please dont report this as duplicate. I searched on the internet for 3 hours now and got nothing. Really pissed off

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Voting to close as you are not asking a question - you pointed out what you believe to be a logical discrepancy, but you have not asked a question. Put a question in your post and I'll reconsider.

Comment: @KingDuken am saying Vrms shiuld be equal to V(dc) and not V(avg). i want to know why wikipedia is saying V(dc)=V(avg)

Comment: Thank you for the amendment. I have retracted the close vote.

Comment: @Adam I would appreciate that

Comment: Please show the part of wikipedia you're actually referring to. I'm not seeing it in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody sensible is saying that the average value of any signal voltage equals its RMS value. Consider a pure sinewave, it has an average value of zero volts (over one complete cycle) yet it has an obvious RMS value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72785/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-ac-dc-circuits-electronics).

Comment: @Andy aka, Your Last comment is exactly what i wanted to hear. The confusion was between V(dc) and equivalent dc voltage.Thanks for being patient with me. One last question why its called V(dc) ( or dc value of a signal ) if it is not an equivalent dc voltage. That makes no sense to me...

Comment: Remember the battery that spent 50% time at 30V and 50% time at 10V? This can be made with a 20V battery in series with an alternating square wave that peaks at 10V and -10V. So, it can be seen that the DC content of the signal is 20V.

Comment: Okay. Thanks man . I think i need to work hard on these things to get good intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Because \$V_{DC}\$ and/or \$V_{AV}\$ <> \$V_{RMS}\$ for these waveforms - they are mathematically distinct.

Quoting [another source](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/average-voltage.html) (which explains things more succinctly than I):

> The main differences between an RMS Voltage and an Average Voltage, is that the mean value of a periodic wave is the average of all the instantaneous areas taken under the curve over a given period of the waveform, and in the case of a sinusoidal quantity, this period is taken as one-half of the cycle of the wave. For convenience the positive half cycle is generally used.
>
> The effective value or root-mean-square (RMS) value of the waveform is the effective heating value of the wave compared to a steady DC value and is the square root of the mean of the squares of the instantaneous values taken over one complete cycle.

Wikipedia is careful to distinguish \$V_{DC}\$ and \$V_{AV}\$ from \$V_{RMS}\$ in all examples on the page you cited.

It is using both \$V_{DC}\$ and \$V_{AV}\$ interchangeably to represent the mathematical mean of the signal. The circled section in the original question shows this:

\$V_{DC}, V_{AV}\$ - The DC or average output voltage.

In the context of this article, the terms DC voltage and average voltage mean the exact same thing - the mathematical mean of the signal.

Comment: Adam thanks for responce. But please read my question carefully. I know avg. Value is not  Dc equivalent heating value. But wikipedia says V(avg) or V(dc) what does that tell you?